# ¿Porque en java no se ejecuta el procedimieto almacenado?

Tags: java, jquery, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

lo que pasa es que tengo en la base de datos un procedimiento almacenado que hace un join entre 2 tablas, pongo una parte del procedimiento

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_VERIFICACIONAPP

@ID VARCHAR(50)

AS BEGIN
DELETE verificacionApp
INSERT INTO verificacionApp(CB,Articulo,Descripcion,Cantidad,CantidadA,Observaciones)

(Select cb.Codigo,vd.Articulo, a.Descripcion1,SUM(vd.Cantidad),0,'No se han verificado'
From VentaD vd
join CB cb on cb.Cuenta=vd.Articulo
join Art a on vd.Articulo=a.Articulo
WHERE ID=@ID
GROUP BY cb.Codigo,vd.Articulo,a.Descripcion1)

SELECT  * FROM verificacionApp

END
```

y en SQLserver se ejecuta bien el procedimieto, nada mas que se le agrego una entrada extra que es modulo.
Yo en java lo mando a llamar asi

```
public void buscarID(String modulo){
        DefaultTableModel tabla = new DefaultTableModel();
        int id=Integer.parseInt(comp.IDvtaJTF.getText());
        if(conectar()){            
            try{   
                comp.BuscarID.setEnabled(false);
                comp.IDvtaJTF.setEnabled(false);
                comp.BuscarCodigo.setEnabled(true);
                comp.EscanerJTF.setEnabled(true);
                comp.ReiniciarBusq.setEnabled(true);
                tabla.addColumn("CodigoBarras");
                tabla.addColumn("Articulo");
                tabla.addColumn("Descripción");
                tabla.addColumn("Cantidad");
                tabla.addColumn("CantidadA");
                tabla.addColumn("Observaciones");
                tabla.addColumn("Modulo");
                cts=cn.prepareCall("{call SP_VERIFICACIONAPP(?,?)}");
                cts.setInt(1, id);
                cts.setString(2, modulo);
                r= cts.executeQuery();
                while(r.next()){
                    Object dato[] = new Object[7];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
                        dato[i] = r.getString(i + 1);
                    tabla.addRow(dato);
                }     
                comp.jTableVTA.setModel(tabla);
            }catch(SQLException e){}       
        }
    }
```

y no se ejecuta nada, la aplicacion no me manda ningun error, pero en la tabla de la interfaz no sale nada, no se ejecuta el procedimiento desde java, pero si lo ejecuto en SQLserver si se ejecuta bien.
tengo algun error en la llamada al procedimiento o que esta mal?

Comment: La base de datos está en el pc de servidor, y javascript es un lenguaje de cliente, puede ser por eso por lo que no se ven. Yo todo lo que he hecho de web relacionado con bases de datos, ha sido con PHP. Un saludo PD: Insisto en que no entiendo muy bien como funciona javascript, pero creo que funciona así.

Comment: @javiertxu18 creo que se refiere a Java, no a Javascript. Son lenguajes diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

La aplicación no te da ningun error porque en el catch no estás haciendo nada, deberias poner código para tratar el supuesto error.

Asi a ojo lo único que veo es que procedimiento solo acepta un parámetro (ID) que es varchar y tu le estas pasando dos, pasándole ademas éste como Int.

Eso asumiendo que el fallo esté ahí y no en la funcion conectar(), que no está incluida en el try, catch. Te recomiendo que además metas esa linea del if también dentro del try.

Comment: Le agregamos el parámetro módulo, que es el que estoy mandando "extra" es un varchar, solo que no tengo el procedimiento actualizado